# Creation of Socket instance blocks thread for random time if no connection available

Tags: android, sockets

Trying to open socket connection in separate thread by calling this:

```
Socket sc = sc = new Socket(address, Integer. parseInt(port));
```

But there is a problem, if there is no active internet connection this thread is blocking, on my htc hero 2.1 for 30 seconds, and my android emulator 2.2 for 2 minutes.

I tryed to use this method before opening connection:

```
public static boolean isOnline()
{
             ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) app.getInstance().getSystemService(Context. CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
             if(null != cm.getActiveNetworkInfo())
                   return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
             return false ;
}


public void run()
{
    if(!isOnline())
        throw new IOException("internet not connected");
    Socket sc = new Socket(address, Integer. parseInt(port));
}
```

And everything is good, But if active connection will lost after isOnline was called, and before new Socket call, its still blocks for random time.

My question is there any possibility to solve that problem? or just block this thread for fixed time for about 2-3 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest calling `thread.interrupt()` after a timeout.

You might also want to get the Android source and see where it's spending all that time.  It might give you some insight on other approaches to dealing with this.

Comment: From another thread.  That thread waits N time, then interrupts/kills the socket connecting thread.  My multi-threading-fu isn't all that great, so maybe I'm misunderstanding `interrupt()`.